# How to properly install and use texlive with package manager

Tags: latex, texlive

I would like to know how to properly install, and use texlive along with the package manager tlmgr in Ubuntu. Here is what I did to install texlive:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-extra texlive-latex-recommended
```

And now I do have texlive, but the package manager is not working. Following is the error

```
sudo tlmgr update -all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
cannot setup TLPDB in /home/kniwor/texmf at /usr/bin/tlmgr line 5336.
```

Is there a better way to install texlive? What can I do to fix the package manager at this point?

Comment: If you do not have any space issues you can go ahead and install the full texlive package: `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`

Comment: Thanks. However I prefer to install only what I need. Mostly because I like to know what I'm using since I use multiple computers to compile my files(work/home etc) and some of them have space issues.

Comment: See also: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114623/installing-texlive-on-ubuntu-revisited

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Just run `tlmgr init-usertree` first and then run `sudo tlmgr update --all`.

---

Maybe you will get:

```
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Initialization failed (in setup_unix_one):
/usr/bin/tlmgr: could not find a usable xzdec.
/usr/bin/tlmgr: Please install xzdec and try again.
Couldn't set up the necessary programs.
Installation of packages is not supported.
Please report to texlive@tug.org.
tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).
```

If so, you have to install the `xzdec` package, from your package manager or through `sudo apt-get install xzdec`.

---

To use the GUI, you also need to install `perl-tk`:

```
sudo apt-get install perl-tk
```

Then you can summon the GUI via:

```
tlmgr --gui
```

And then hit the `Load Default` button.

Comment: This works fabulously.

Comment: TeXLive 2013 version included in Ubuntu 14.04 may stop working with tlmgr, since TeXLive 2014 was released in the meantime. See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/486170/upgrade-from-tex-live-from-2013-to-2014-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: I was missing the `xzdec` package on a fresh installation of 16.04. Worked fine afterwards!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use `tlmgr` on Ubuntu you basically have two options:

1. [Install texlive from scratch and create a dummy package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/18782)
2. Use [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu), as described in [this answer on tex.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/171560/18782)

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @Kyle_the_hacker gave a straightforward way to setup the user mode management, which is required for Debian-based distros. However, at the time I am writing this answer, before doing anything, update all yields

```
❯ sudo tlmgr update -all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: not a directory, not loading: /root/texmf
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!
```

The `.md` contains

```markdown
TeX Live Manager (tlmgr) on Debian
==================================

Rationale
---------

The TeX Live Manager (tlmgr) is the main configuration and package
management program in *upstream* TeX Live. Thus, the Debian TeX
Team has often received requests for providing `tlmgr` in Debian.

Since package management (installation, update, ...) is the responsability
of APT (apt, apt-get, ...), `tlmgr` *cannot* interfere with it, but uses
the "TeX Live Manager User Mode" instead.

For details concerning the User Mode, see https://tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#USER-MODE

Warning
-------

`tlmgr` on Debian automatically switches to user mode. Consequences of this are:

- an initial setup step is necessary (see the documentation)
- packages will be installed into `TEXMFHOME` which normally is `$HOME/texmf`
- packages installed into `TEXMFHOME` will override system-wide installed 
  packages, that means a later system update will **not** be seen by TeX
- not all packages can be installed using the user mode, see the above link
  for details

We strongly recommend **not** to user the TeX Live Manager user mode on Debian.
If you are using it despite the warnings, be prepared to fix your own TeX system.

If you want the full power of TeX Live Manager, we recommend installing
TeX Live from upstream https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html
See also "Integrating vanilla TeX Live with Debian" here https://tug.org/texlive/debian.html
```

Although it says it isn't recommended to use `tlmgr` on Debian, if you follow the @Kyle_the_hacker's steps, you might get this error

```
❯ tlmgr update -all
(running on Debian, switching to user mode!)
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)

tlmgr: Local TeX Live (2021) is older than remote repository (2023).
Cross release updates are only supported with
  update-tlmgr-latest(.sh/.exe) --update
See https://tug.org/texlive/upgrade.html for details.
```

If you installed TeX Live from the Ubuntu's package manager (`apt`, probably from the `texlive-full` package), AFAIK you can do nothing if the latest  version available on `apt` isn't the most updated version...

Therefore, the accepted answer didn't work for these cases. Instead, you must install the CTAN package manually by following these steps:

1. Download A package from CTAN.
2. Extract the files and place them in an appropriate directory (e.g. `/usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/footmisc/`).
3. [Opitional, some packages already have the `.sty` file] Generate the .sty file by running latex on the appropriate source files (e.g., `latex footmisc.ins` and `latex footmisc.dtx`).
4. Update the ls-R file in this source tree:  `cd /usr/local/share/texmf/; sudo mktexlsr`.

This way worked for me. For more info, [see here](https://jvgomez.github.io/pages/manually-install-latex-packages-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: "Download the package from CTAN"...?

Comment: @JamieVicary What is the problem?

Comment: If you added the information about how to do that it could make your answer more useful to others.

Comment: @JamieVicary It is as obvious as I stated: Go to a website named (guess what?) ctan.org -> Go to any [pkg](https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode) you want to download -> Click on a giant blue button named (guess what?) "Download", and you made it.