# Upgrade from Tex Live from 2013 to 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, latex, texlive

According to the [TeX Live website](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) TeX Live 2014 was released one week ago (14 June 2014). How do I upgrade from TeX Live 2013 to TeX Live 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: Even worse, the TeXLive 2013 version included in Ubuntu stopped working with `tlmgr`: `tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository [...] (2014--2014) do not include the version of the local installation (2013).`

Comment: @gertvdijk Yes the same happend to me. So I was forced to install TeX Live 2014..

Comment: After following the selected answer, I am still getting the same error as @gertvdijk. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Lucas You did not follow all steps then. You've probably missed the PATH changes or to log out and log back in after as you're getting the old tlmgr...

Comment: Yes, I even re-did the install (full, default, installation) and checked everything over. `tlmgr --version` says `2014` but `tlmgr update --self` and `tlmgr update --all` give the error from your first comment. All latex commands work fine, and use `/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/..` so I guess I'm ok for now. Any clarification on the `tlmgr update` error would be helpful.

Comment: @Lucas I have the same problem - did manual upgrade, `tlmgr --version` and `tex --version` both report 2014, but I get the `The TeX Live versions supported by the repository [...] (2014--2014) do not include the version of the local installation (2013)` error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Download the "netinstaller" for TeXLive `install-tl-unx.tar.gz` from any [CTAN mirror](http://ctan.org/mirrors/), e.g. [this one](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz).

   This "netinstaller" is not a full download, but just a small executable and will download all packages from the internet based on the requirements you set later. For more information, see the [install guide](https://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html).
2. Extract it somewhere, e.g. in `~/texlive/2014`.

   ```
   mkdir ~/texlive/2014
   cd ~/texlive/2014
   tar -xf /path/to/install-tl-unx.tar.gz
   cd install-tl-20140831 # depends on your installer version, adjust to your situation
   ```
3. Run the `install-tl` binary with root privileges, e.g. (adjust to your situation):

   ```
   sudo ./install-tl
   ```

   Note: If you have a single-user machine, or don't have root
   privileges, I would recommend installing to your home directory
   instead (omit `sudo` in the previous command). The reason is that
   commands like `tlmgr` (see below) will not work out of the box if they
   are run with `sudo`, see [Setting TeX Live path for root](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66498/setting-tex-live-path-for-root) for
   more information.

   Optionally:

   - Add the `-select-repository` option in order to select a CTAN mirror nearby before downloading anything.
   - Add the `-gui=perltk` option to use a GUI installer. Install the `perl-tk` package first! (`sudo apt-get install perl-tk`) See the screenshot below how it should look like.
   - Configure only specific collections by choosing the menu option <kbd>C</kbd> to save bandwidth and space. Be warned: the default set of 47 collections will yield more than 2GB of traffic and disk usage. You can always install more collections later with the TeXLive package manager (`tlmgr`) and the `collection-`-prefixed meta-packages.
4. Choose <kbd>I</kbd> for install in the menu. (If not in GUI mode)

   It installs in `/usr/local/texlive/2014` by default.
5. The installer output suggests to adjust some environment variables. Do so by editing your `~/.profile` (or `~/.bashrc` if you like) and add the following lines:

   ```
   TEXDIR="/usr/local/texlive/2014"
   export PATH=$TEXDIR/bin/i386-linux:$PATH    # for 32-bit installation
   export PATH=$TEXDIR/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH  # for 64-bit installation
   export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/doc/info
   export MANPATH=$MANPATH:$TEXDIR/texmf-dist/doc/man
   ```

   Log out and log back in to receive the new variables, or, source the file, e.g. `source ~/.profile` to activate it for your current shell. This last step should make sure your application actually use your new 2014 local TeXLive installation rather than the Ubuntu packaged one. Some tools will require you to configure that yourself, see for example [this on TeXWorks](https://askubuntu.com/a/518702/88802).

   Here's how the GUI installer looks like:

   [image: install-tl]
6. Finally, to install new packages you need to setup a Texlive package database (TLPDB). See [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137428/tlmgr-cannot-setup-tlpdb) for more information. In summary, you have to run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xzdec
   sudo tlmgr init-usertree
   ```

   then you can install a new package, for example, to install package `wrapfig`, run:

   ```
   sudo env PATH="$PATH" tlmgr install wrapfig
   ```

   or if you installed in your home directory, you can omit `sudo`:

   ```
   tlmgr install wrapfig
   ```

Comment: this is correct. You can use `tlmgr update --self` and `tlmgr update --all` to keep your installation up-to-date.

Comment: The 2014 release is not yet available from the repositories, so right now a manual install is the only way to do it. The downside to this approach is that you will to manage the updates yourself.

Comment: Is it available from repositories yet? If not, when? Do I have to add some PPA or will it be available as a "normal" update in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? Thanks.

Comment: Make sure to set the required collections with the `C` option in the menu, otherwise it downloads 2896 packages and takes 20 minutes on my 100Mbit internet connection... I don't want to install *all* TeXLive packages...

Comment: You will probably need to "fake" the installed packages to avoid the dependency system installing duplicate versions of the tex system if you install something depending on tex. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95373/38080

Comment: sudo tlmgr init-usertree does not work for me ("command not found"), but running it without sudo works.

Comment: @JulianSchuessler Yes you are right, thanks for pointing it out. See my updated answer for an explanation and a solution.