# How do I install TeXWorks with tlmgr?

Tags: package-management, latex, texlive

I've installed TeXLive 2014 in a local installation using the `install-tl.sh` method and selected the collection `collection-texworks`. I expected to be able to run the `texworks` binary after installation, but there's no such binary in `/usr/local`. Also, `tlmgr` reports it cannot find the binary.

What am I doing wrong?

---

```
⟫ tlmgr info texworks
package:     texworks
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   Cross-platform friendly front end.
longdesc:    See http://tug.org/texworks for information and downloads. TeX Live includes executables only for Windows.
installed:   Yes
revision:    30136
tlmgr: cannot find depending packagetexworks.x86_64-linux
sizes:       doc: 5k, run: 14981k
relocatable: No
collection:  collection-texworks

⟫ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr install texworks
tlmgr: package repository http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

(nothing more, exit status 0)

```
⟫ find /usr/local -type f -name "texworks"
```

(no output)

```
⟫ which texworks
```

(no output)

Answer (score 2):

Read more carefully in the `tlmgr info texworks` output:

> TeX Live includes executables only for Windows.

Use the PPA (https://launchpad.net/~texworks/+archive/ubuntu/stable) or the official Ubuntu packages.

The TeXWorks installation as installed by the Ubuntu packages use the Ubuntu TeXLive installation, not the locally installed ones in `/usr/local`. In order to change that, edit the preferences in TeXWorks and set the path to the TeXLive installation on top:

[image]

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, but it was certainly not clear to me when I had the same problem that `tlmgr info texworks` was something I should type to help resolve the issue...