# How to install TexLive 2014?

Tags: latex, texlive

I have installed TexLive2014 under scheme-full using the latest iso file. But terminal still doesn't recognise the 'tex' or 'latex' commands. Do I need to install extra packages outside of the iso file? If so, why are they not included in the iso file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two possibilities here:

1. install the version released with your Ubuntu. For example, 14.04 ships with TeXLive 2013 (*not* 2014). This is the easiest way; just type

   ```
   sudo apt-get texlive-full
   ```

   and be done.
2. You can install directly the newest version of TeXLive. Follow for example the instruction in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu/95373#95373. Be warned that installing software outside the package management can led to some complex situation; in that post you have some hint.
3. There are instruction also in [Upgrade from Tex Live from 2013 to 2014 on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486170/upgrade-from-tex-live-from-2013-to-2014-on-ubuntu-14-04)

The option #1 is the recommended one, unless you really *need* some cutting edge version of the packages (I am for example a quite advanced LaTeX user, and rarely do).

That said, it seems that the only problem you have is that the installation path is not in your `PATH`. It is explained in "finishing the installation" in the first linked post, or in point #5 of the second one(1). If you find that part too complex, I really advise to follow option #1.

---

(1) they are different methods/philosophies, but they have the same final effect.

Comment: I was able to follow the instruction 2 and make the existing 2014 installation work. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You should install it from the official Ubuntu sources.

```
sudo apt-get install texlive
```