# XeLaTeX on Ubuntu TeXLive Error with pst-3dplot

Tags: latex, texlive

I'm having problems with a pst-3dplot example under XeLaTeX on Ubuntu 14.04 and all later versions.

The problem apparently is a matrix transformation error:

```
** WARNING ** Transformation matrix not invertible.
** WARNING ** --- M = [-154.772 0 0 0 6447.73 -40.3858]
```

Here is a MWE that produced the error on my machine (Xubuntu 14.04 64bit, TeXLive 2014 and all later versions):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{pst-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-4,-4)(3,4)
\psset{Alpha=30}
\pstThreeDCoor[xMin=-4,yMin=-4,zMin=-4]
\pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,-3){\fbox{\Huge\red xy plane}}
%\pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,0){\fbox{\Huge\red xy plane}}
%\pstPlanePut[plane=xy](0,0,3){\fbox{\Huge\red xy plane}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

I had previously posted to problem on the TeX.SX site
[here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246486/pst-3dplot-error-transformation-matrix-not-invertible).
But people don't know what to do or simply don't care. 
I'm migrating from OS X and my decision for/against Ubuntu depends on this mere detail, since I use it professionally.

Comment: A little bit complicated: This is my error messag, if a test your example: `Undefined control sequence. \pstPlanePut`

Comment: I'm not sure what has happened to you here. `\pstPlanePut` is a function defined in the pst-3dplot package, see the manual here:
[https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot). It may be a linking problem..

Comment: I have TeXLive 2015 installed (Ubuntu 15.04) which includes PSTricks 2.57. To this version the `\pstPlanetPut` function is unknown. This function is not referenced in the [User's Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pstricks/base/doc/pst-user.pdf) and neither does it show in the [project home page](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi). I would advise you to contact the [package mantainer](https://www.ctan.org/author/voss) inquiring how to obtain a version of PSTricks that includes this particular function. This question is therefore misplaced at AskUbuntu.

Comment: The function `\pstPlanetPut` is part of the `pst-3dplot` package and properly documented there. My question is Ubuntu specific as the problem did not turn up on my osx machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been able to find out most of what is going on here:

1. An up-to-date version of TeXLive is necessary. For some reason the TL version shipped with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from the repository is not recent enough. It is possible to get the latest version (TeXLive 2015) via the install scripts from CTAN mirror (see this
   [answer on SX](https://askubuntu.com/questions/486170/upgrade-from-tex-live-from-2013-to-2014-on-ubuntu-14-04)) or from a Ubuntu specific script (see another
   [answer on SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114623/installing-texlive-on-ubuntu-revisited)
   )
2. Run the latex file with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` to get the desired results. It appears that `XeLaTeX` encounters a bug when placing 3D objects (compare 
   [this on SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/244718/pst-3dplot-error-with-iiidlabels/252700#252700)) -- so that does not work at the moment.
   Doing `latex->dvips->ps2pdf` will successfully translate to this:
   ![latex-dvips-ps2pdf-result][4]

Comment: not enought reputation to add image -- will add it asap.