# How to make ubuntu identify your latest texlive version (2015)

Tags: latex

I have installed texlive 2015 but when i try to  do `tex -version` the shell prints that the current version is TeX 3.1415926 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)

texlive 2015 has been installed under `:/usr/local/texlive/2015`

Comment: For which Ubuntu release?

Comment: 14.04 Ubuntu...

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `dpkg -l 'texlive'; dpkg -l 'texlive-full'`

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/486328/16395 ?

Comment: ...or `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/tex --version`.... (Check the path, I have not installed it)

Comment: I suspect, the path `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin` isn't in your `/etc/environment`. and you should remove your old installation via `sudo apt-get remove 'texlive*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the version being installed via the Ubuntu repositories:

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove 'texlive*'
   ```
2. Edit the path environment in `/etc/environment`:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/environment
   ```

   Add the path to the texlive installation, e.g. for a **32-bit** installation:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
   ```

   or for a **64-bit** installation:

   ```
   PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"
   ```

   Replace `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/i386-linux` with the path in your system.

Comment: `/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux` in a 64 bit Ubuntu OS

Comment: i edited my PATH variable to PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x68_64-linux:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games" but when i type tex -version still 2013 is shown

Comment: Open a terminal and give me the output of `echo $PATH`

Comment: '`x68_64`' in the path should be '`x86_64`'