# gedit external tools cannot locate latexmk

Tags: gedit, latex

I am using following in gedit external tools

```
#!/bin/sh
file=${GEDIT_CURRENT_DOCUMENT_NAME%}
filename="${file%.*}"
ext=${file##*.}
latexmk $filename; xdg-open $filename.pdf
```

Wheni run the command, i got the following output

```
/home/quanta/.config/gedit/tools/new-tool-2: 27: /home/quanta/.config/gedit/tools/new-tool-2: latexmk: not found
```

I have latexmk installed and the file gets compiled easily in terminal using latexmk.
Kindly guide me on why gedit is unable to locate latexmk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to be a problem with $PATH. Put the directory where you find latexmk (result of `which latexmk`) in front of the latexmk in your script.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  Is there a robust method as gedit handles latex(which is in the same directory) very well. Here are the contents of my bashrc file                                            export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH; 
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH; 
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH;

Comment: If latexmk was installed from `latexmk` package, then it should be located in `/usr/bin/latexmk`. AFAIK the `/usr/bin` is a standard path. @neutrino for me it seems that you chose non-optimal method of installing LaTeX tools...

Comment: I understood my problem from https://askubuntu.com/questions/694021/how-to-make-ubuntu-identify-your-latest-texlive-version-2015.  It appears in addition to bashrc, one has to edit path in /etc/environment as well.